# Does the miswak help with digestion, eyesight, headache, memory or illness?

Tags: medical-science, hygiene, islam

The [miswak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miswak) is a traditional Middle-Eastern toothbrush (so to speak) make from a twig of a particular branch, that is claimed to be especially effective. The dental efficacy has been [studied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miswak#Science), but frankly isn't very interesting - it is, essentially, just another form of abrasion for removing debris and plaque.

What *is more interesting* is that Islamic culture claims a myriad of *other* benefits, beyond dental. This is due to a [sunnah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunnah) on the subject, with the consequence that this is believed by a lot of Muslims.

I'll ignore the religious aspects (i.e. apparently Allah greatly magnifies his rewards for people using the miswak), as I believe such is beyond this site's remit; however, any [Google search for "miswak benefits"](http://www.google.com/search?q=miswak+benefits) will reveal the other claims, including:

- [cures illness](http://www.turntoislam.com/forum/showthread.php?t=28460)
- [improves memory](http://www.zikr.co.uk/content/view/50/90/)
- [cures headache](http://benefitof.net/benefits-of-miswak/)
- [improves eyesight](http://www.salamcards.com/static/MiswakTheNaturalToothbrush.shtml)
- [makes teeth glow](http://www.islam.tc/Miswaak/)
- [helps digestion](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10150663601979200.406638.229961919199&type=3)

Many of these seem quite extraordinary claims (for a toothbrush), but also feel like they should be pretty easy to investigate. While extraordinary, some are also not entirely beyond plausibility - for example, the headache/willow/salicylic-acid/aspirin connection.

So: has any research even been done into the non-dental, non-religious aspects of these claims? Or more simply: does the miswak help with digestion, eyesight, headache, memory or illness?

Comment: I hadn't read your last paragraph correctly: it was already enough to make this large, but not list.

Comment: I didn't understand either of the comments above, but edited in what I hope is an acceptable solution. The scope of this question remains rather broad which will make it difficult to answer.

Comment: @odd: the question was already acceptable, but thanks for improving it!

Comment: I think the fact is Miswak may not provide the same cleanliness as toothbrush with tooth paste. Remember that miswak does not need a tooth paste.

Comment: @Believer I deliberately side-lined the **dental** claims; that *has* been studied. The question directly addresses the *non-dental*, *non-religious* claims. Also - when studied, the effect of the active ingredient was only observed at high concentration (i.e. far above what miswak may provide), so the anti-bacterial effect *from an active agent* is also wildly exaggerated commonly. But that is off-topic to this question.

Comment: @MarcGravell Interesting. I'd be interested in the answer myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The search for "miswak" returns 72 hits on PubMed, which is one of the most comprehensive databases of references and abstracts on life sciences and biomedical topics. I have briefly reviewed the abstracts of each, and **none support anything but claims related to oral hygiene**.

Having said that, there are numerous studies supporting the link between oral hygiene and general health. See, for example, "Periodontitis as risk factor for acute myocardial infarction: A case control study" in *Heart Views*, 2013 Jan;14(1):5-11.

So, in a sense, the claims have some truth to them in so far as taking care of your teeth and mouth, whether by miswak or with a toothbrush, is better than doing nothing.<sup>†</sup>

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Please note that this answer does not constitute medical advice. It is only meant to summarize published research related to the topic and limited to the cited sources. Consult your physician about what these results may mean for your health.</sub>

Comment: For the curious: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=miswak

Comment: Personally, I'm content to say that this answers it, and the answer is "no, there are no such studies" (note: I'm not the "bounty" person, so while I can accept this answer, my accepting it is unrelated to the bounty)